# Convert an upper to lower triangle matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, reshape, reshape2

I looked inot several posts, but I still couldn't find a way to just transform an upper triangle matrix into a lower triangle matrix.

I just want this:

```
    1   2   3
a   10  11  12
b       13  14
c           15
```

To become this:

```
    a   b   c
1   10
2   11  13
3   12  14  15
```

Answer (score 0):

We just need to transpose it

```
t(m1)
```